# How do you re-export a generic function with concrete types?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a generic function `foo<T>()`. However, I want to specialize the function for the type `usize`. I could declare another function and call the generic function. However, I am wondering if there is any syntax sugar I could use, such as (pseudo code) `pub use foo::<usize> as foo_usize`.

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn foo<T: Debug>(a: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", a)
}

// I do not want generics, as I need to export this function as extern with #[no_mangle]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_usize(a: &usize) {
    foo::<usize>(a)
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no such syntax, but this could be fairly easily simulated with custom attribute. I'll try and do this a bit later.

Comment: The function `foo_usize()` has a different calling convention than instantiations of the original generic function. This isn't just a matter of re-exporting a name – you need a wrapper to translate between the calling conventions. I'd suggest you stick with the code you have. It's simple and makes quite clear what's going on. Any wrappers to make this code more succinct on the surface will only introduce unnecessary complexity and hide what's actually happening, for no tangible benefit in exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform the monomorphization yourself by explicitly listing out the function and performing the call:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn foo<T: Debug>(a: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", a)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_usize(a: &usize) {
    foo::<usize>(a)
}
```